# Quicker way to prove convergence or divergence?

Tags: calculus

What is a quicker way to prove or disprove the convergence of $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(s-2)t}t^3\ dt$$
Instead of actually computing the integral

Comment: Are you sure it converges?  Do you know which of $s<2$, $s=2$, or $s>2$ holds, and why it might matter to your question?

Comment: This question was on an exam that involved the use of Laplace Transforms, however, being that it is a bilateral Laplace transform, I wanted to know if there was an easier way to prove its divergence without computing the actual integral.

Answer (score 1):

If $s-2>0$ then $t\rightarrow -\infty\Longrightarrow e^{-(s-2)t}t^{3}\rightarrow-\infty$ and the integral diverges.

If $s-2<0$ then $t\rightarrow \infty\Longrightarrow e^{(2-s)t}t^{3}\rightarrow\infty$ and the integral diverges.

If $s-2=0$ the integral is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^{3}{\rm d}t$ and it's undefined.

Are you sure that's the integral you need to calculate? Maybe the limits are $0\rightarrow\infty$?